# Trying to take a screenshot of Windows Phone in XNA

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I am currently using a piece of code to try and take a screenshot of my current screen in XNA. I have written the code in VB.NET. This is:

```
    Public Sub SaveScore()
    Dim screenshottexture As RenderTarget2D = New RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, False, SurfaceFormat.Color, Nothing)
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(screenshottexture)
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Nothing)
    Using stream As New MemoryStream()
        screenshottexture.SaveAsJpeg(stream, screenshottexture.Width, screenshottexture.Height)
        stream.Position = 0
        Dim media As New MediaLibrary()
        media.SavePicture("screenshot.jpg", stream)
    End Using
    screenshottaken = True
    screenshottexture.Dispose()
```

However, although this code saves a picture to my saved pictures album, it just appears as a purple screen. Can anybody see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try forcing your game to draw before you set the `rendertarget` to `nothing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in a game I was working on a couple of years ago.  Example is in C#, but it should be easily translatable:

```
Texture2D screenshot;
RenderTarget2D render;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice);
//Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

render = new RenderTarget2D(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice, 800, 480);

Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(render);

spriteBatch = CreateScreenshot(spriteBatch);

Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

screenshot = render as Texture2D;
```

At that point, you should be able to use the Texture2d(screenshot) in the same/very similar way you are currently using your "screenshottexture" variable.

**EDIT** - Didn't realize I was references the CreateScreenshot() method in the above code:

```
    public SpriteBatch CreateScreenshot(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        return spriteBatch;
    }
```

Comment: So once this is done i then pass it through my stream to save it?

Comment: Also is 'CreateScreenshot' some kind of class?

Comment: Didn't realize I was referencing this method in the original code.  I added it to the main answer.